# Big jump or small jumps?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy

To travel a certain distance s, is it more energy efficient to use one massive jump, or several small jumps?

(First approach deleted, didn't make sense) This approach is probably a lot better.
Firstly, the energy consumed by our body is proportional to the kinetic energy we gain, and therefore proportional to our initial speed squared.
$$
Energy\;used\;\alpha\;Initial\;speed^2
$$
Then, I managed to prove that the angle at which the largest distance is covered given a initial speed is 45 degrees, meaning that all jumps, regardless if you are going for one big one or several small ones, are all at 45 degrees. Then by mashing through equations I found initial speed squared is proportional to distance.(checked on wiki: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_of_a_projectile)
$$
Initial\;speed^2\;\alpha\;Distance\;Traveled
$$
Therefore: (drumroll)
$$
Energy\;Used\;\alpha\;Distance\;Traveled
$$
Hang on... Doesn't this mean, IT DOESN'T MATTER IF I TAKE SMALL JUMPS OR ONE LARGE ONE???
Now here, as an example, lets just introduce this fictional measure for energy, the Joshe. We can say
$$
(Energy\;Used)joshes\; = \;(Distance\;Traveled)metres
$$

To travel 100 metres, with one large jump, it costs 100 joshes of energy, with 10 small jumps it costs 10*10 joshes of energy, or 100 joshes of energy. Thus I can conclude that in an ideal world, it doesn't matter if you use one big jump, or several small jumps, to cover a distance, they all use the same amount of energy? Or not? There are several things I have ignored, and in practice, it is impossible to just simply jump however far you want. So my question is, is this a good approximation? If not, in real life, is it actually better to take a big jump or several small ones.

Comment: I'm not sure how you prove your assertions, but the first 2 lead you to conclude that the energy used is proportional to the initial speed, and this is incorrect. The energy spent during the time the force acts, must be equal to the kinetic energy gained, which is proportional to the initial speed squared.

Comment: Of course, in real life, our muscles are not 100% efficient, which means we need more energy than the kinetic energy we gain (extreme case: If just holding a heavy weight, from a physical point of view we don't do *any* work, yet our muscles still consume energy in order to sustain the force; that energy is completely converted to heat).

Answer (score 1):

Looking at real life jumpers, Kangaroos, the key element seems to be the efficiency with which the jump energy can be recovered upon landing. This is usually done in all animals, including Humans, by storing energy in the connective tendons.